# Lenovo G500 how do I turn off secure boot to install Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation, uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows 8.1. I have gone through the manuals in the internet and in "askUbuntu" but I have found no solution.

I have turn off "fast boot" option in Windows as suggested in the manual. When I restart the computer I don't see the UEFI settings option (pressing Shift while restarting the computer) which is required to turn off "secure boot" option. I am unable to turn this off as I dont see UEFI settings option after restart.

I am using Lenovo G500 Laptop with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Is Ubuntu also installed? - You can choose to install Ubuntu next to Windows in the setup.

Comment: See [G500 Secure Boot Status Disabled cant change](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G500-Secure-Boot-Status-Disabled-cant-change/td-p/1442715)

Comment: @bain You should add these instructions as an answer.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Do they actually work? I do not have a G500 to test.

Comment: @bain It worked for the user over there, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

From [Lenovo community: G500 Secure Boot Status Disabled cant change](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G500-Secure-Boot-Status-Disabled-cant-change/td-p/1442715)

> Open the bios menu. If your secure boot is enabled, then in the
>   security tab you will get two more options to "Reset to setup mode"
>   and "Restore Factory Keys". just hit enter on those two options.
>
> then exit saving changes and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Near the power button there is a smaller button. Instead of power press this button and a menu will appear. You just have to choose BIOS Setup or Boot menu if you just want to change the boot order.